# MySQL Query with distinct on a column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table (with 100k+ rows):

```
room_id | emote_id | count | since
----------------------------------------
      1 |       22 |    718| 1577135778
      1 |       23 |    124| 1577135178
      1 |       24 |    842| 1577135641
      2 |       22 |    124| 1577135748
      2 |       23 |    345| 1577136441
      2 |       24 |     43| 1577543578
      3 |       22 |     94| 1572135778
      3 |       23 |   4718| 1577135641
      3 |       24 |     18| 1577134661
      4 |       22 |     78| 1577125641
      4 |       23 |    128| 1577135778
      4 |       24 |    278| 1577132577
```

I want to get for each emote_id the row where count is the highest for this emote_id

So for this example I'd like to get this as response:

```
room_id | emote_id | count | since
----------------------------------------
      1 |       22 |    718| 1577135778
      3 |       23 |   4718| 1577135641
      1 |       24 |    842| 1577135641
```

I'm stuck at building the query and need help. :(

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? And what should happen in case of a tie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested subquery with `max()` aggregation

```
select t1.*
  from tab t1
  join (select emote_id, max(count) as count
          from tab
         group by emote_id ) t2
    on t1.emote_id = t2.emote_id
   and t1.count = t2.count
```

for db version 8+ you can use window analytic functions such as `dense_rank()`:

```
select room_id, emote_id, count, since
  from
  (
   select t.*, dense_rank() over (partition by emote_id order by count desc) as dr
     from tab t
  ) tt
  where tt.dr = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4f58d392510bca61aee6782eaea72f17)</kbd>

*All matching maximum values for `count` return through use of `dense_rank()` in case of tie( having equal valued `count` for any of `emote_id` ). If analytic function was `row_number()`, then only one row would return even if tie occurs.*

Comment: You forgot to join on the count.

Comment: Sorry im not good at SQL, what is happening in the query? What does the  `tab t) tt` mean? My table is called `leaderboard`

Comment: just replace tab  with leaderboard

Comment: yes, because I didn't know your table name, named it `tab` @just-clean-70

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Hi its me again. Do you know how I could modify the query to get the N first results for each emote_id?